# Incorrect reading data from .bin file

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryfiles

I have two programs: one is test that students take and second is for teachers(teachers create some variants of test and add questions to it); Teacher program creates .bin files with tests and then student's open and take those tests. Data structure(`class Question`) are similiar in both programs;
Teacher's program class code:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Question
    {
        public Question(string q_text, Dictionary<string, bool> ans, Image img)
        {
            text = q_text;
            answers = ans;
            image = img;
            isAnswered = false;
        }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, bool> answers { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public bool isAnswered;

        public static void PersistObject(Dictionary<int, Question> q, Stream stream)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, q);
            stream.Close();
        }

        public static Dictionary<int, Question> LoadObject(Stream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                Dictionary<int, Question> deserializedObject = (Dictionary<int, Question>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();
                return deserializedObject;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and student's program class code:

```
[Serializable]
    class Question
    {
        public Question(string text, Image img, Dictionary<string, bool> ans)
        {
            question_text = text;
            image = img;
            answers = ans;
            isAnswered = false;
        }
        public string question_text { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, bool> answers { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public bool isAnswered;

        public static Dictionary<int, Question> LoadObject(Stream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                Dictionary<int, Question> deserializedObject = (Dictionary<int, Question>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();
                return deserializedObject;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I try to read some test in student program:

```
string file =  path + test_number + ".bin";
Stream myStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
questions = Question.LoadObject(myStream);
```

it sets `questions` to null. But when I read those files in teachers program then it's OK.(perhaps, it's OK, because I create those files in teachers mode too). Type of `questions` is `Dictionary<int,Question>` .What's the problem?

Comment: If you didn't swallow the exception you would probably be presented with a meaningful error that will help you debug this problem.

Comment: How I can debug reading from bin file? it seems to be imposible.

Comment: Instead of returning `null` from the `catch` block write to the debug log.

Comment: For starters, how about just setting a breakpoint inside the catch clauses, so that the debugger will intercept the program when an exception occurs?

Comment: elgonzo, exception occurs when I try tu use questions, because it's null(not when reading from file). Reading from file method works good. Because the same method works good in teacher program.

Comment: @user3560681, imagine, inside your *LoadObject* occurs an exception because of a problem. The exception would tell you about the problem. But... What happens there in *LoadObject* method when an exception occurs?

Comment: elgonzo, at this line occurs exception: Dictionary<int, Question> deserializedObject = (Dictionary<int, Question>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

Comment: Good -- what exception exactly - what does it tell you? (Hint: Look at the public members of both Question classes)

Comment: exception text: "Unable to find assembly 'KR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Comment: Hehe, i was not expecting this exception :) Good that i asked...

Comment: KR is teachers program

Comment: So, I can read those bin files only in the program that created those bin files?

Comment: I know what is going on... [let's continue in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53854/discussion-between-user3560681-and-elgonzo)